# Spring Security: DelegatingFilterProxy переполняет стек

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

Настраиваю Spring Security и столкнулся с проблемой когда в конфигурации указано доступ к определенным адресам предоставлять только при авторизации все равно можно обратится к ним без авторизации.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
        .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();
    }
}
```

---

```
@RestController
public class TestController {

    @PostMapping(value = "/test")
    public List<String> postHello(@RequestBody ArrayList<String> strings){
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        return strings
                .stream()
                .map(s -> "Print "+s)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

}
```

---

При такой конфигурации я отправлю запрос на http://localhost:8080/test в тело запроса помещаю `["one","two"]` и ожидаю что запрос не пройдет так как в настройках Spring Security я указал, что все пути должны проходить проверку авторизации `anyRequest().authenticated()`.

После просмотра гугла я увидел, что возможно проблема заключается в том, что  в `web.xml` нет настроек фильтра.

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
    </filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>targetBeanName</param-name>
        <param-value>springSecurityFilterChain</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

После добавления фильтра я получаю ошибку что нет такого бина `springSecurityFilterChain`. Иду добавлять бин в конфиг...

```
<bean 
        id="springSecurityFilterChain" 
        class="org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy"/>
```

Сервер стратует нормально, но стоит отправить запрос как получаю следующую ошибку:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Filter execution threw an exception
java.lang.StackOverflowError
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270)
...
...
```

---

Не могу понять, что именно я делаю не так. Возможно этот фильтр вообще не нужен и нужно лишь подправить конфиги.
Если кто то уже сталкивался с такой проблемой буду благодарен за помощь.

[build.gradle](https://pastebin.com/M4qtx0cH)
[application-context.xml](https://pastebin.com/xPYJ2V6h)
[dispatcher-servlet.xml](https://pastebin.com/KWEDSPmm)
[web.xml](https://pastebin.com/nTNMZnHB)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел по какой причине не запускался фильтр `DelegatingFilterProxy`.
Проблема была  в том что `dispatcher-servlet.xml` был не прописан в `web.xml`.

После добавления в `web.xml` следующего блока, все заработало корректно:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/application-context.xml /WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```